# my pre-processing for audio file not working

Tags: python

```
def preprocess(file_path, frame_length = 2048, hop_length = 512):
    '''
    A process to an audio .wav file before execcuting a prediction.
      Arguments:
      - file_path - The system path to the audio file.
      - frame_length - Length of the frame over which to compute the speech features. default: 2048
      - hop_length - Number of samples to advance for each frame. default: 512

      Return:
        'X_3D' variable, containing a shape of: (batch, timesteps, feature) for a single file (batch = 1).
    ''' 
    # Fetch sample rate.
    _, sr = librosa.load(path = file_path, sr = None)
    # Load audio file
    rawsound = AudioSegment.from_file(file_path, duration = None) 
    # Normalize to 5 dBFS 
    normalizedsound = effects.normalize(rawsound, headroom = 5.0) 
    # Transform the audio file to np.array of samples
    normal_x = np.array(normalizedsound.get_array_of_samples(), dtype = 'float32') 
    # Noise reduction                 
    final_x = nr.reduce_noise(normal_x, sr=sr, use_tensorflow=True)
        
        
    f1 = librosa.feature.rms(final_x, frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length, center=True, pad_mode='reflect').T # Energy - Root Mean Square
    f2 = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(final_x, frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length,center=True).T # ZCR
    f3 = librosa.feature.mfcc(final_x, sr=sr, S=None, n_mfcc=13, hop_length = hop_length).T # MFCC   
    X = np.concatenate((f1, f2, f3), axis = 1)
    
    X_3D = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
    
    return X_3D
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22520\4235689130.py in <module>
51     print("* done recording")
52
---> 53     x = preprocess(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILE) # 'output.wav' file preprocessing.
54     # Model's prediction => an 8 emotion probabilities array.
55     predictions = model.predict(x, use_multiprocessing=True)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22520\3553863170.py in preprocess(file_path, frame_length, hop_length)
23
24
---> 25     f1 = libr`your text`osa.feature.rms(final_x, frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length, center=True, pad_mode='reflect').T # Energy - Root Mean Square
26     f2 = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(final_x, frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length,center=True).T # ZCR
27     f3 = librosa.feature.mfcc(final_x, sr=sr, S=None, n_mfcc=13, hop_length = hop_length).T # MFCC

TypeError: rms() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 positional argument (and 4 keyword-only arguments) were given

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look over the [documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.rms.html) of the rms function from librosa, as it is the one that is causing the issue.
Basically, the error is due to you giving a positional argument to the function, where it only accept keyword arguments (meaning `some_keyword_arg_name=some_value`).

```py
f1 = librosa.feature.rms(y=final_x, frame_length=frame_length, hop_length=hop_length, center=True, pad_mode='reflect').T # Energy - Root Mean Square
```

is hopefully what you are aiming for.